# Use windows service or Timer to perform action

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, timer

I need your expert opinion in one subject.
Take in mind I never did nothing like this before, so be patience , please !

I developed a windows Form app that perform multiple actions..
One of those actions - write2Database() - is to read a file that is in a folder and write that info to the database (mysql) (after that the file is deleted).

Everything is ok with that, but now i was asked to implement a new functionality, that is : even if the program is not open
it should check that folder (every x minutes) and if there is a file them execute the write2Database() method.
When the app is open it should do the same.

I´m so lost, I don´t know where to start, should I use windows services( i don´t know exaclly how they work)....

Can anyone explain me the steps that i have to follow, please !!

Thanks.

Comment: As I told, I so lost I don´t know where to start, all I have is the method working ( the app is ready )  I just need to implement this new funcionality .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use FileSystemWatcher instead of a timer to monitor if a file appears in a folder?
You could implement it in a windows service which allows it to work in the background all the time and not dependent on an application being run.

Here is a simple example of how to implement a filesystemwatcher in a windows service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18521/How-to-implement-a-simple-filewatcher-Windows-serv

Answer (score 1):

Make a new windows service and remove the functionality from the application

Windows services are surprisingly easy, and common so there will be more than a few tutorials on it. Also they are a standard project type in Visual Studio, don't forget to set the service to run on startup

A colleague had a similar problem a while back, don't use a timer or while(true) loop, that is wasteful, use a file event listener to detect a file being created in the folder in question.

Comment: Agree, I would use topshelf for it: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf, very easy to use.

Comment: @Colin Steel , I will have a try like you said, but one more question,should I create the windows service inside my windows form?  And is it possible to interact between the windows form and the windows service? I mean say in the windows form, from x in x minutes to verify the folder ?

Comment: No the Service will have to be its own project, and it will appear in the Services list in TaskManager, as for comms between apps and services I have never had to do that myself. StackOverflow does have questions on how to comm between two applications so that may be a starting point, other than that I can only think of using network/port communications between the two, useful to do now if your service is going to go on a server